# React Hook Form : validation error object is empty during first submit event

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form in React-TypeScript project. I'm having the following issue.

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

type FormData = {
  name: string
  mobile: string
}

export default function Form() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm<FormData>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      mobile: "",
    },
  })

  const { errors } = formState

  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  const onError = (err: any) => {
    console.log(err, errors)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        {...register("name", { required: true })}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Mobile"
        {...register("mobile", { required: true })}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Console Output
[image]

The *errors* object in *formState* is an empty object during the first submit event, but the second callback of *handleSubmit* always returned the correct error object (which will be called when validation fails). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I put this in a CSB, don't see the same problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-ytwc7p?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. and Controller Component solved this.

```
<Input {...register('email')} placeholder="email" />

<Controller
      control={control}
      name="email"
      render={({ field }) => {
        return <Input {...field} placeholder="email" />;
      }}
    />
```